# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH when installing python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, virtualenv

I'm trying to install a new Python environment on my shared hosting. I follow the steps written in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv):

```
mkdir ~/src
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-2.7.1.tar.gz
cd Python-2.7.1
mkdir ~/.localpython
./configure --prefix=/home/<user>/.localpython
make
make install
```

After coming to the `./configure --prefix=/home/<user>/.localpython` command, I get the following output:

```
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux3
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home3/mikos89/Python-2.7.1':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

How can this problem be solved? I've been trying to find a solution for 3 hours, but I'm still stuck in one place.

**UPDATE**

Hostgator [does not allow gcc](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/compatible-technologies) on their shared accounts:

Comment: exactly same issue

Comment: You should try to find prebuild binaries for your system. It's the easiest way if you don't have root access.

Answer (score 715):

The gcc compiler is not in your `$PATH`.
It means either you dont have gcc installed or it's not in your $PATH variable.

To install gcc use this: (run as root)

- Redhat base:

  ```
   yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
  ```
- Debian base:

  ```
   apt-get install build-essential
  ```
- openSUSE base:

  ```
   zypper install --type pattern devel_basis
  ```
- Alpine:

  ```
   apk add build-base
  ```

Comment: I like the methods of installing [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/build-essential), which contains gcc, g++, make, etc.

Comment: Is there an alternative for zypper?

Comment: this is shared hosting, how is this even an accepted solution?  we need python, in come cases for node, which is also going in as user level, no root.  this is a deal breaker for all this, needing root.  this is supposed to be a non root procedure IMO

Comment: Actually it's yum groupinstall "Development *T*ools" in CentOS 7

Comment: How would you determine if its installed but not in your $PATH variable?

Comment: hi there, do we have a Windows 10 equivalent?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, I have linux centos 6.5, please advise what to do..

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install build-essential``` worked for me

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment

For Ubuntu Users: 
sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev

Answer (score 116):

You need to run

```
yum install gcc
```

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7. Thanks

Comment: Worked on Debian 4.9. Thanks

Comment: Worked on CentOS 8. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the error "Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf". I have Bluehost shared hosting.

Comment: Hey @PaulChrisJones, I ran into same problem when I tried installing gcc in my blueshot hosting acc using ssh. I ran into this because my configure file woud not run. If you managed to find a solution please let me know. It would be of great help !

Comment: Worked on AlmaLinux OS 8

Comment: Worked on Rocky Linux 8 ($ dnf install gcc)

Answer (score 93):

**For Ubuntu / Debian :**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**For RHEL/CentOS**

```
sudo yum install gcc glibc glibc-common gd gd-devel -y
```

or

```
 sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools" -y
```

For more details, refer to [this link](http://thelinuxfaq.com/74-error-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-linux).

Answer (score 81):

Assuming you're on a debain/ubuntu system, you will need to run the following first:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I got this response after typing your code: sudo: unable to mkdir /var/db/sudo: No such file or directory

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for <usrname>: 
<usrname> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: @mik.ro what OS/distribution are you running. Are you logged in as root by any chance?

Comment: i'm using hostgator, it's on CentOS x86.

Comment: @TomSwifty I got the mentioned message every time I want to login as a root. I'm gonna contact hostgator to clarify it.

Comment: Ok, i've checked hostgator website and the solution is very simple and sad: they don't allow gcc on their shared servers [link](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/compatible-technologies) If anyone has an idea, how can I install another python distribution on their shared hosting I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Great answer, fixed my problem,

Answer (score 26):

`sudo apt install build-essential` is the command.

However, if you get the "**the package can be found**" kind of error, run

- `sudo apt update` first
- then `sudo apt install build-essential`

This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: worked for me, don't forget to ```sudo apt update``` . Always a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 18):

You would need to install it as non-root, since it's shared hosting. [Here](http://luiarthur.github.io/gccinstall) is a tutorial that  goes through how to do this step.

```
cd ~/src
wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

or equivalent gcc source, then

```
tar -xvf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.2.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
make
make install
```

Then add to .bashrc, or equivalent:

```
export PATH=~/gcc-5.2.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/gcc-5.2.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/gcc-5.2.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: when execute `$PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go` still result the same error **configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH**

Comment: I got "configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" when executed $PWD... Is there a known solution???

Comment: I had a similar issue when using Bluehost's hosting services. I had to call support to request to be added to their compiler group(which they have an example for enabling python).
After they granted it, I was able to call make, which is currently still compiling after an hour.

Comment: I'm on a NAS drive. I don't have access to `apt`, `yum` or even `dpkg`. How can I install this file on a folder already pre-compiled so to speak. I believe the poster is describing compiling the application but unfortunately I can't compile the C compiler without a C compiler ....

Answer (score 16):

If you are using alphine with docker, do this:

```
apk --update add gcc make g++ zlib-dev
```

Comment: `apk add --no-cache git autoconf automake gawk build-base`

Answer (score 13):

Issue:

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

I fixed the issue by executing the following command:

```
yum install gcc
```

to install gcc.

Answer (score 9):

Get someone with access to the root account on that server to run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. If you don't know who has root access, contact the support team for your shared hosting and ask them.

Edit: If you aren't allowed access to root, you aren't ever going to get it working. You'll have to change hosting provider I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9):

Run `apt-get install gcc` in Suse Linux.

Comment: should be:  `sudo zypper install gcc` for Suse Linux

Answer (score 7):

On Arch Linux run the following:

`sudo pacman -S base-devel`

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. With no additional setup.

Answer (score 4):

#### For Ubuntu/Debian, run

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y build-essential
```

Remember to add the flag `-y` to accept to continue by default.

Answer (score 2):

You need just to install `build-essential` on **Debian-family** and `Development tools` on **RedHat-family**.

Answer (score 2):

In a shared hosting, gcc compiler is disabled by default (in a terminal write `gcc --version` and it must return 'Permission denied' if installed...). It's very important to the next step.

Now, contact the support team and request to add your user id to 'compiler group'. This solves your problem and other - for example, you will be able to execute 'make' and 'make install' without problems, install the pillow library, etc.

Forget about 'sudo' or 'apk' commands. They are also disabled by default.