# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH while installing the C compiler

Tags: centos, rhel

I am facing the following error, while installing the C compiler itself (`gcc gnu`).

```
configure: error: in `/home/gcc-5.3.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Noting that I have tried the solutions listed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python) with no success.

OS: RHEL6 and CentOS

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to install a compiler to compile. The solutions in the mentioned question should work:

```
yum install gcc
```

or

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

After that, try to run your compiler to make sure everything is aligned:

```
gcc
```