# /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: node.js, centos, hummus.js, gipc

I am working in node js. I have installed hummus package. It installed properly. I am using this package for modifying the pdf files. While downloading the pdf I am calling hummus. Onclick of download I am getting this error.

```
Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/www/html/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/hummus/hummus.js:5:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /var/www/html/app/routes.js:2250:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

With the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317265/1525221) I have updated glibc. But still I am getting the same error. Please help me to find out the issue.
I am using CentOs 6.9

Comment: Add the output of `env` on your machine. Also `ldd /var/www/html/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node` if it works

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: What is the version of glibc that you have upgraded to? Also, can you provide the output of these commands 1) env 2) ldd --version 3) yum list glibc

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Comment: I tried but not worked. Now I changed my server to ubuntu.

Answer (score 50):

You need to install glibc alongside your current installation of glibc as you cannot update to glibc 2.14 directly in centos 6.x safely. Follow the steps below to install glibc 2.14:

1. `mkdir ~/glibc214`
2. `cd ~/glibc214`
3. `wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz`
4. `tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz`
5. `cd glibc-2.14`
6. `mkdir build`
7. `cd build`
8. `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14`
9. `make -j4`
10. `sudo make install`
11. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib` (for current login session) OR  add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib` in the /etc/environment and perform `source /etc/environment`(to add env variable permanently)

Comment: at ```sudo make install``` ,  `Can't open configuration file /opt/glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf: `

Comment: at ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14 i got configure: error: in `/root/glibc214/glibc-2.14/build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: @BhartiLadumor Refer this link for more info:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python

Comment: Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't generally work, for reasons explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617

Comment: To fix: `glibc-2.14/build/elf/ldconfig: Can't open configuration file glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory`
I did: `cd glibc-2.14/etc/`, `sh -c "echo 'glibc-2.14/lib' >> ld.so.conf"`

Comment: oh my ... everything going well but ... 
[a@a build]$ ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.33
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/alex-chama/glibc233/glibc-2.33/build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
[a@a build]$ make -j4
bash: make: orden no encontrada

Im in arhclinux I think was the same

Answer (score 5):

To install locally, 8th line in first answer became

```
../configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

then we do not need the "sudo" in 10th line. i.e.

```
make install
```

is enough.

You might need to

```
touch $HOME/.local/etc/ld.so.conf
```

line 11 becomes:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.local/lib"
```

in `.bash_profile` of el6

Answer (score 3):

line 8. `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14` was erroring out for me

In the end I had to use the following

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14  libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can not reproduce this error. However, this could work:

1. Download the whole hummusjs package from the author https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS (e. g. as zip).
2. Add a new scripts entry in its package.json: `"rebuild": "node-pre-gyp rebuild"`.
3. cd into the package folder at your desktop and run "npm install".
4. For safety delete the .binding and .build folder.
5. Edit the binding.gyp file in the package (new section before 'sources'):

   ```
           ],
   #added by 11AND2
   "conditions": [
   [ 'OS=="linux"',
   {
       "cflags": ["-include gcc-preinclude.h"]
   }
   ]],
   #end added by 11AND2
      'sources': [
   ```
6. Then run `npm run rebuild` and wait :-)
7. Try the example which failed and report back. You can also execute `npm run test` to run the module test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue while installing python packages:

```
pip install requests_gssapi
# OSError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/krb5/1.20.1/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so)
```

Reinstalling [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with latest gcc fixed that:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew install gcc
```