# ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found after importing tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I'm setting up tensorflow in linux web hosting for flask application. I have installed tensorflow but when i import it i get the following errors
i tried to upgrade GLIBC but still doesn't work.
i have python 3.5.7 i cant upgrade it because i'm in web hosting
all solution in [/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found. Why am I getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error)
didnt work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/malnetxy/virtualenv/Server/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: What's your *Lnx* version (`uname -a` or `cat /proc/version` might contain relevant info)? Also what's your *libc* version (`ldd --version`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/lib64/libc.so.6: version \`GLIBC\_2.14' not found. Why am I getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error)

Comment: @CristiFati Linux version 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.67.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm03.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jul 10 09:47:30 EDT 2019 
and ldd (GNU libc) 2.12

Comment: Very short form: If the available binary packages aren't compatible with your system, compile from source instead of trying to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using an Anaconda environment. Then, you will be able to install Tensorflow and everything you need, also glibc executing: `conda install -c asmeurer glibc`

Comment: After installing that, I now get a segmentation fault. This is apparently a common behaviour: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/g/anaconda/c/_jkSod9itDE