# Broke yum on Centos 6.10, cannot install missing GLIBC in error due to missing libunwind

Tags: glibc, centos6, yum, libunwind

I was installing nvidia-drivers on Centos 6.10 which included a --skip-broken flag and may have broken yum. Whenever I ran `yum` commands this error pops up.

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1)

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 20 2019, 14:14:55)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I stumbled upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error)  which talks about installing the missing GLIBC version, but I ran into this error in step 8 `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14`

```
checking for forced unwind support... no
configure: error: forced unwind support is required
```

Which then took me to this [forum thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-in-configure-glibc-2-3-4-a-321255/) that states I should install libunwind via yum. Which was my original problem, thus leaving me at an impasse. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall GCC, or more precisely the `libgcc` package. Something overwrote `/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1` with an incompatible version. You should be able to download the `libgcc` RPM package from a mirror, and then run:

```
# rpm --reinstall libgcc-4.4.7-23.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

This should still work because RPM itself does not depend on `libgcc_s`.

In general, if you need newer versions of these core system libraries (glibc, libstdc++, libgcc_s), you need to upgrade the entire operating system. Even if you manage to replace them in a consistent fashion, you are running something that isn't very close to the original operating system anymore. At that point, it is more prudent to upgrade, because that will give you a consistent system that has been tested by many others.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up following your advice of updating to Centos 7 and didn't run into this error again.