# Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: linux, glibc

I am facing with the following error when i try to run a program on centos 6.

> /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

I used `ldd --version` to find out what is the current version of `glibc`:

> ldd (GNU libc) 2.17

which is higher than `2.14` and consequently, I should not face with this error. what should i do to resolve this error?

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error

Answer (score 3):

According to [distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos), CentOS 6.10 shipped with GLIBC-2.12.

> I used `ldd --version`

`ldd` is highly unreliable for anything (it will lie to you).

What *matters* is what version of `/lib64/libc.so.6` you have. You can find out by running it, like so:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, I don't. I mean _exactly_ what I wrote.

Comment: That works too -- I always just listed the symlink.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used your proposed command and the result was: `GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.17` still higher than 2.14.

Comment: @MR7 That is very surprising. Please edit your question to add output from `env LD_DEBUG=files,libs /path/to/your/program`.

Comment: I have  `version 2.12,` while the software required `2.14`