# Run selenium with python in shared server + GLIBC library

Tags: python, selenium, glibc

Trying to use Selenium, with Chrome and Firefox browsers, on a shared server I get an error. As a first step
download the binaries and drivers (chromedriver and geckodriver respectively) of both browsers in my user's home.

Setting binary_location and executable_path in the webdriver options correctly finds everything but still gives an error.

When executing on the server manually for example chromedriver I get:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14 'not found (required by ./chromedriver)

/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16 'not found (required by ./chromedriver)
```

And with firefox:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17 'not found (required by firefox)
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14 'not found (required by firefox)
```

So I try to install GLIBC_2.17 to solve the problems by following these posts: [glibc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error) and [install it as non root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/python-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python)

The code is the following:

```
# path new library
mkdir /home/db/glibc217
# path original files
mkdir /home/db/glibc217/download
# path install
mkdir /home/db/glibc217/install

# get files
cd /home/db/glibc217/download
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.17.tar.gz

# unzip => create /home/db/glibc217/glibc-2.17
tar zxvf /home/db/glibc217/download/glibc-2.17.tar.gz -C /home/db/glibc217/

# build
cd /home/db/glibc217/glibc-2.17
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/home/db/glibc217/install
make -j4
make install
```

When finished, give the following message:

```
/home/db/glibc217/glibc-2.17/build/elf/ldconfig: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /home/db/glibc217/install/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
```

Additionally the environment has this variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/db/glibc217/install/lib
```

After installing version 2.17 gives the same messages for missing versions of the library for Chrome (it asked for 2.14 and 2.16) and for both browsers when executing the python script it reports :

```
/home/db/virtualenv/py_test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin: error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen (): Invalid argument
```

Is there a missing step in the installation? Can something be done to avoid the final warning of the installation? Should the same procedure be done for all required library versions? Any ideas to fix the final python error?
Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

> `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/db/glibc217/install/lib`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not work, and what to do instead.

> `error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen (): Invalid argument`

The error above is a pretty clear indication of mismatch between `ld-linux` and `libc.so.6` (other indications are outright crashes).