# NodeJS Linux Executable runs on Ubuntu but not on RedHat

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, redhat

Like the title suggests, I created a nodejs program that I packaged into an executable using the node pkg module. My boss wanted a version that could run on Linux, so I followed the instructions from the pkg github page and created one for windows and one for linux. I tested the linux program on a virtual Ubuntu machine I created, and it runs just fine.

However, when my boss tried running the code on his Redhat Linux server, he got this error:

```
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node)
```

I tried all day but I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem, or what's causing it. If it helps, he's running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, with a gcc version 4.4.7-23.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: can it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564999/lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found-why-am-i-getting-this-error

Comment: Linux binaries aren't portable between systems by default. If you want them to be, you will need to ship all the dependent libraries either statically linked, or as separate dynamic libraries with LD_LIBRARY_PATH or the executable's rpath configured accordingly.