# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH - Installing Python and GCC

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I'm trying to install Python-3.6.5 on a machine that does not have any package manager installed, like apt-get or yum.  I do have root access.

I can wget Python, but when I run the ./configure, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Okay, so next I try to install GCC.  I follow [these instructions](http://luiarthur.github.io/gccinstall):

```
cd /bin
wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz
tar -xvf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.5
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.5/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.5 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
```

And on that last command, I once again get:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Lots of googling and reading led me to suggestion to add CC=/usr/bin/gcc like so:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-x $PWD/../gcc-4.8.5/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.5 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
```

That gets me a new error:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Any ideas here?  I'm really at a loss here, I've spent a long time trying to figure this one out and it's annoying me to no end.

Comment: Can you post the relevant log output from the configure run? Also, something is *really* whack with your system if a proper C compiler is not in PATH.

Comment: Compile Python and/or GCC on a different system and copy the binaries onto yours.

Comment: It would help if we knew what kind of Linux system this is. Something like this is *very* OS dependent. I could see it being Arch Linux though. Just a guess.

Comment: Read through `config.log` to see *why* it thinks your system-installed gcc is broken. Most likely, that system-installed gcc **is** in fact broken, and, well, not being able to compile things without a working compiler shouldn't be any kind of a surprise.

Comment: I kept fighting with it and it turns out gcc was installed but there was a stupid PATH problem that was causing the issue.  I should have gone down that path (get it) sooner

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It must be fix.
(Referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python))