# How to Have Pycrypto at Docker Properly Working?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, pycrypto

I am using [Pychromeless repo](https://github.com/21buttons/pychromeless) with success at AWS lambda.

But now I need to use pycrypto dependency, but I am getting

`configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`
 
when running `make docker-build` 
(after placing `pycrypto==2.6.1` at `requirements.txt` file).

There's [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python) and someone said about the same problem:

"The gcc compiler is not in your $PATH. It means either you dont have gcc installed or it's not in your $PATH variable".

So tried placing `apt-get install build-essential` at Dockerfile, but I got

`/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found`

Then, I tried with `yum install gcc`

only to get

`The command '/bin/sh -c yum install gcc' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Docker-lambda [info page] (https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) says:

```
This project consists of a set of Docker images for each of the supported Lambda runtimes.

There are also a set of build images that include packages like gcc-c++, git, zip and the aws-cli for compiling and deploying.
```

So I guess I shouldn't be needing to install gcc. Maybe the gcc compiler is not in $PATH, but I don't know what to do to fix that.

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM lambci/lambda:python3.6
MAINTAINER tech@21buttons.com

USER root

ENV APP_DIR /var/task

WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY bin ./bin
COPY lib ./lib

RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR/lib
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t /var/task/lib
```

Any help on solving this?

Comment: `RUN yum update -y && yum install -y gcc` to install `gcc`.

Comment: @masseyb: same answer: `Service 'lambda' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y && yum install -y gcc' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: What is that lambci/lambda image based on? What’s it built FROM?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/

Comment: They say: `There are also a set of build images that include packages like gcc-c++, git, zip and the aws-cli for compiling and deploying.`

Comment: And if I `docker run -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 bash` + `which gcc`, I get `/usr/bin/gcc`. I don't get it...

Comment: Maybe the gcc compiler is not in $PATH, but I don't know what to do to fix that. Can you help me with a Docker line to achieve that?

Comment: I’ll have a look / post an answer after my work day if no one beats me to it  Note: you can edit a comment for 5 minutes, don’t need to post multiple comments (got a chatroom for that).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for that.

Comment: @masseyb, any help on this? `pycryptodome` did not work on AWS lambda...

Answer (score 5):

Well, well, well...today was a lucky day for me.

So simple: all I had to do was replace

`pycrypto==2.6.1`

by

`pycryptodome`

on my requirements.txt file.

This [thread](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/263) says: "Highly recommend NOT to use pycrypto. It is old and not maintained and contains many vulnerabilities. Use pycryptodome instead - it is compatible and up to date".

And that's it! Docker builds just fine with `pycryptodome`.