# scons upgrade to 2.3 failed (linux RHEL 2.6)

Tags: scons

I am updating an old linux (RHEL 2.6.9) scons (v0.96) to the current v2.3

Frankly scons has been working quite well - just trying to get rid of some scons warnings that have resulted from changes to my Scons files as I've upgraded other platforms to v2.3

First of all, the download `scons-2.3.0-1.noarch.rpm` resulted in a "Package Not Found" (python) alert. Python is certainly present (albeit old as well - v2.3.4)

I then downloaded `scons-2.3.0.zip` - and (as root) executed 'python setup.py install'. That proceeded to completion without any errors. Me thinks.

But, alas, in a Terminal window, I type:

```
$scons -v

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scons", line 192, in ?
    SCons.Script.main()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

Duh. Certainly my old reliable scons is broken :(

Comments? Suggestions?

-harry

BTW, I am not a python expert at all; have been able to support this scons build simply by example and minimal changes - which is to the credit of this tool!

Comment: I don't think scons 2.3.0 will work with such an old version of python. I believe it should at least be python 2.7, and pre 3.0.

Comment: Yup. Looks like you are absolutely correct. python 2.4 is the minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed python 2.3 was too old (v2.4 is the minimum for scone v2.3).

I installed python 2.7.6 (see [On linux SUSE or RedHat, how do I load Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149361/on-linux-suse-or-redhat-how-do-i-load-python-2-7))

And, after updating $PATH appropriately (see above) and linking /usr/local/bin/python to /usr/local/bin/python2.7, scons was one again working!