# syntax error when installing python module

Tags: python, pip

I used

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
```

and then

```
python get-pip.py
```

and get error:

```
File "get-pip.py", line 20281
"""
```

Comment: It'd be lovely to see the full error. Anyway, line 20281 is the end of the multi-line binary string. Not sure why that's a syntax error though.

Comment: File "get-pip.py", line 20281
    """
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me on Ubuntu 12.04.  Are you sure the wget completed okay?  What is the md5sum of the file?  Mine is 49808f380bf193aef5be27e2d7f90503.

Comment: The md5sum is the same.

Comment: Maybe it's the version of python? Although I don't know if that would do it.

Comment: yes, thanks. It seems so. I am going to go to python 3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a version of Python installed that is at least 2.6. For more information see the following link:
http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#id6

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but then on i realized my Python version was 2.4. Install the [2.7 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149361/on-linux-suse-or-redhat-how-do-i-load-python-2-7) and run the `python2.7 get-pip.py` 
It worked for me!