# Installing python 2.7 on RHEL 4 machine

Tags: python, linux

Does installing Python2.7.10 in red hat 4.1 having python 2.4.3 already installed causes problem ? need to install CFFI through PIP command. But it says bash :pip: command not found and Yum module not found.

Any ways to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you change the system default python then it does not matter if you have 10000 versions of python installed, you may find virtualenv or pyenv to be a better solution though

Answer (score 0):

For Installing python alongside your default one, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149361/on-linux-suse-or-redhat-how-do-i-load-python-2-7).

But for installing `pip`, you can follow as below:

```
easy_install pip
```

Comment: Is it possible to install `pip` using `yum`.

Comment: No, python-pip package included in EPEL  5,6. [check this](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install_requirements_linux/#centos-rhel)

Comment: @padraic : sorry i think that i have changed the system python so that my repositories gets deleted or may be not supporting to python 2.7. Any suggestions to reset the default python  ?

Comment: search in SO, for recovering python, if nothing found, ask again.

Comment: when i do any yum command it shows .... Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
No Match for argument: zlib-devel
Nothing to do

Comment: when i give yum -y install python-pip it says Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
No Match for argument: python-pip
Nothing to do
what does it means ?????

Comment: That means you broke the yum, [try to recover yum](http://serverfault.com/questions/410075/reinstalling-python-on-centos-to-be-able-to-use-yum)

Comment: Thanks for the info bro... can you please tell me whats he possible reasons for " name error _cffi_backend name is not defined